# more no of columns in google column charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

i am using Google column charts but the no of vertical bars equals no of data on x axis and y axis using the given code. But i am trying to achieve a chart like this http://www.teluguinvestor.com/live/nifty-live-open-interest-tracker.php which has only 5 X axis data and 4 Y axis data but no of vertical bars are more

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you would like?  The example you point to is structurally the same as the code in your question.

Comment: please check it carefully its not the same the link i gave is of X Y graph where both the X axis and  Y axis is being used as scale but the code mentioned is not for the same. In the link the no of column bars are more but X axis intervals are only 5 where as in the code i mentioned the no of bars are same as intervals in X axis bar. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  The data used does not have fewer rows or columns, it just uses a continuous axis type.  Change your first column to a `number`, `date`, `datetime`, or `timeofday` instead of `string` and you will get the same effect.